# How to share code between two GWT projects?

Tags: gwt

I'm working on two GWT projects in Eclipse which share some of their classes.Project A has base source files and some functionality. I don’t have change access to this project, although I can read source. Project B is my target work project.

Problem

I have added each source folder from project-A to project-B launches configurations. When I execute project-B as GWT project, it does not read the source files from project-A.

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/projects/eclipse-workspaces/ws-wars-1.3.2/project-b/common/com/wars/shared/framework/util/I18NImpl.java'
[ERROR] Line 19: No source code is available for type com.wars.shared.framework.util.I18NUtil; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

What could be causing that error? Any hints are highly appreciated.

Best regards,

Vijay Shanker

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642797/how-to-share-code-between-multiple-gwt-eclipse-projects. It is seems to be duplicate to this. but please let me know how to Inherit project A's gwt.xml in project B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the project-b in your projectA.gwt.xml file.

if the projectB.gwt.xml file is in package com.projectb.util then add the following line

```
<inherits name='com.projectb.util.projectB'/>
```

in projectA.gwt.xml file